# Maya style functions in Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling

Does Blender 2.8 have in-built Mayalike pie menu to change viewpoint?

And is there a way to show wireframe of objects in solid/shaded view??

My keyboard also doesn't have a numpad by the way.

Thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please ask only one question per post, make as many as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For views you can alt middle-mouse and it changes in the direction your mouse is going.

For your wireframe problem, go to object tab, viewport display, tick wireframe.
[image]

To make it global:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kiskit! I appreciate your response! 

I just tried the "gizmo" looking thing at hte topright of the viewport and it seems to suffice for alternating between top/right/left for now :\

I asked because sometimes I need a flat view for modeling over a reference image. 

And as for the wireframe, is there no way to have a global viewport setting?

I even looked in the keymap settings and there's no option to enable that individual wireframe box per object T.T.

I mean it'll do for now but sadface T.T

Comment: The middle mouse thing is a bit hard to get used to IMO but probably easier for someone who doesn't have a numpad. There is something in the options to simulate numpad: Preferences/Input/Emulate Numpad. No idea what it does though.
I edited my answer so that it includes the wireframe thing for all objects on screen.

Comment: Thank you Kiskit!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!